# Find if phonenumbers exist between 2 columns

Tags: sql, t-sql, loops, between

I am trying to pass two 10 digit telephone number block using TSQL.

Lets say:

```
TelephoneNumber1: 1234560095
TelephoneNumber2: 1234561005
```

My Table consists of 3 columns:

```
ID, StartBlock, EndBlock
1, 5671231000, 5671232000
2, 1234561000, 1234562000
3, 2175551200, 2175551300
```

So what I am trying to do is find all the numbers between `TelephoneNumber1` and `TelephoneNumber2` and see if it exists between any records between `StartBlock` and `EndBlock` in the table.

In this example, it would find a number already in use in the second record because
when `1234560095` gets to `1234561000`, it will find it in already in use.

How do I accomplish this to find a number in use between the StartBlock and EndBlock?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
declare @T table
(
  ID int,
  StartBlock bigint, 
  EndBlock bigint
)

insert into @T values
(1, 5671231000, 5671232000),
(2, 1234561000, 1234562000),
(3, 2175551200, 2175551300)

declare @TelephoneNumber1 bigint 
declare @TelephoneNumber2 bigint 

set @TelephoneNumber1 = 1234560095
set @TelephoneNumber2 = 1234561005

select * 
from @T
where StartBlock <= @TelephoneNumber2 and 
      EndBlock >= @TelephoneNumber1
```

Comment: This will work and a bit shorter.  Very similar to the one if revised from the above poster by @mikeH-R.  That code modified would have been 
    select * from Mytable
Where (StartBlock>=@TelephoneNumber1 and StartBlock<=@TelephoneNumber2) 
Or (EndBlock>=@TelephoneNumber1 and EndBlock<=@TelephoneNumber2)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I'm missing something but wouldn't it just be:

```
SELECT * from MYTABLE 
WHERE (StartBlock=>TelehoneNumber1 AND StartBlock<=TelephoneNumber2) 
OR (EndBlock=>TelehoneNumber1 AND EndBlock<=TelephoneNumber2)
```

EDIT: just looked at this and saw BETWEEN, another option:
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp

Comment: He wants all records where the range of numbers between StartBlock and EndBlock is in the range of numbers between TelehoneNumber1  and  TelehoneNumber2.

Comment: ah so we're checking if part of the ranges overlap and my query doesn't cover the case where TelephoneNumber1 and TelephoneNumber2 are both between startblock and endblock, is that right?

Comment: can't comment on njk's answer (which I agree with) but I think now that I (think) I understand the question don't we need the additional line OR StartBlock <= '1234560095' AND EndBlock >= '1234560095'

Comment: @MikeH-R: Yes, that's what i've understood. Consider that all EndBlock are `1234561006`, then it would be larger than the second number `1234561005`. But it should be included in the result since the range between the first and the second number includes a valid number (f.e. `1234561005`).

Comment: @Tim Schmelter awesome and so that gets fixed with the addition of the or line. (if I'm understanding right), thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @MikeH-R, can you change your syntax for me?  I was running an alternate test for TelephoneNumber1 and TelephoneNumber2 inputs.  If I change it to TelephoneNumber1: 1234562000 and TelephoneNumber2: 1234562005, it wont return the answer of record Ref ID 2.  I think it needs a >= and a <= in the code.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
SELECT * FROM tel
WHERE StartBlock <= '1234561005' AND EndBlock >= '1234561005'
```

**Result**

```
| ID | STARTBLOCK |   ENDBLOCK |
--------------------------------
|  2 | 1234561000 | 1235552000 |
```

### [See a demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e1e40/3)

Comment: He wants all records where the range of numbers between StartBlock and EndBlock is in the range of numbers between TelehoneNumber1  and  TelehoneNumber2. Btw, you're using just the first number. I would know how to do it with C# (`Enumerable.Range)`) but not with T-SQL.

Comment: @njk Shouldn't it be more along the line of having `StartBlock >= '1234561005' AND EndBlock <= '1234561005'`, so that it includes everything in between along with the start and end block?

Answer (score 1):

This can be accomplished by simply doing:

```
SELECT * FROM tblName
WHERE StartBlock >= '5671231000' AND EndBlock <= '5671232000'
```

**Result:**

```
| ID | StartBlock | EndBlock |
--------------------------------
| 1  | 5671231000 | 5671232000 |
--------------------------------
| 4  | 5671231120 | 5671231010 |
--------------------------------
| 5  | 5671231540 | 5671231999 |
```

It should produce a result with the start and end block, including everything that falls between. Have a look at these [TSQL example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187922.aspx) where you will find two ways how to accomplish this.

**[Demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/32d1d/1)**.

Comment: @kereypowell, this would not give me the result if I use
    TelephoneNumber1: 5671230098
    TelephoneNumber2: 5671231005
It should return record id 1 only in your example, correct?

Comment: @CharlesBernardes that's correct. Did you look at the TSQL example link I included?

Comment: when I plug in the TelephoneNumber1: 5671230098 TelephoneNumber2: 5671231005, it did not work for me in your example link.